# Very large file located within ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.lminhtm.tempmonitor/db.realm

Tags: macos, catalina, ssd, storage

I am on a Mac Mini with a 1TB SSD. After a few years my SSD is running out of space, while I keep all my user data on an external drive. My system is loaded with Multimedia Apps Photoshop, Final Cut Pro, Logic Pro X, Garage Band and many others.
When trying to find the file(s) that can be removed on the SSD, using CleanMyMac X function of Space Lens, I bump into a very large file in /Users/username/Library/Group Containers/group.com.lminhtm.tempmonitor/db.realm. This file is a whacking 378GB!
Through Google searches I can’t find any mention of this file.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109028/discussion-on-question-by-roderick-very-large-file-located-within-library-grou).

Answer (score 6):

Group Containers are basically Containers, which are sandboxes for applications to store date (user data, caches, logs, etc), except the Group part means that it's at a developer level. This could be used to, for instance, keep a user logged into the same account across multiple apps made by the same developer. That said, it could be used for anything, which is what this appears to be.

You could check with the developer, in this case: https://github.com/lminhtm. Otherwise, I'd make a backup and delete (or just move it to a different location), then test any apps you have from this developer (maybe [this one?](https://www.vimistudios.com/temp-monitor)).

Comment: Great sleuthing on the temp monitor - very likely the instigator for that file!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to back up the file and delete it. You can also watch the date - is it growing and being updated regularly or static with no changes for some time?

There are unix command-line tools that can track which process has the file open if it’s getting updates on a daily or more often basis.

Lastly. You could uninstall any third party temperature tracking. Coconut Battery, menu bar controls like iStat pro and others have logging features you may not have intended to collect data and store it in this database. One thing for sure, it’s not part of the OS so you can delete it and restart your Mac without causing harm to the system. You can then watch for an error in any programs if they recreate the file or throw an error trying to read a missing file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much for the answers/suggestions! I haven't found the reason for the existence of the file, but I deleted it and have been waiting for the last 2 days for any mishaps, and no further errors until now. Thanks a lot for the suggestions.